# When is it appropriate to mark services as not stoppable?

Tags: windows-services

Services can be marked as "not stoppable":

- In C/C++ by specifying `SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP` flag when calling [SetServiceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686241%28VS.85%29.aspx) (see [SERVICE_STATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685996%28VS.85%29.aspx) for details).
- If .NET, by set [ServiceBase.CanStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canstop.aspx) to `false`.

However, is this good practice? It means that even a user with administrator privileges cannot stop such a service in a clean manner. (It would still be possible to kill it, but this would prevent proper cleanup. And if there are other services running in the same process, they would be killed as well.)

In my specific case, I have a service which controls a scientific instrument. It has been suggested to make the service not stoppable while it is acquiring data from the instrument in order to prevent losing the data being acquired. I should add that:

- We grant non-administrator users the right to start/stop the service
- We have program that provides a UI to start/stop this service. This program will issue a warning if the user tries to stop the service during acquisition. However, it is of course also possible to stop is with `SC.EXE` or the "Services" snap-in. In this case, there is no warning.

Does Microsoft (or anyone else) provide guidance?

Answer (score 0):

My own stance so far is that marking a service not stoppable is a drastic measure that should be used sparingly. Acceptable uses would be:

- For brief periods of time, to protect critical operations that should not be interrupted
- For services that are critical for the operation or security of the OS

My example would not fall under those criteria, so should be stoppable